# Using LISTAGG function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have two tables

```
category
--------

id      product     seq_num
cat12   prod12      0
cat23   prod12      1
cat34   prod12      2

prod
-----

sku     prod    seq_num
sku123  prod12  0
sku234  prod12  1
sku345  prod12  2
```

I am trying to use LISTAGG function and bring output like:

```
output
------
skuid   prod    catids
sku123  prod12  cat12,cat23,cat34
sku234  prod12  cat12,cat23,cat34
sku345  prod12  cat12,cat23,cat34
```

When i use category table alone i am able to use LISTAGG and get the output aggregated properly(without skuid)

using below query:

```
SELECT product,LISTAGG(id, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS catids
FROM category
GROUP BY product;
```

but i am not able to join this with prod table and get the desired output. 
Please help.

Comment: @Aleksej Sorry posted incompletely. Edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it after the join:

```
SELECT s.sku,t.product,
       LISTAGG(t.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS catids
FROM category t
INNER JOIN prod s
 ON(t.product = s.prod)
GROUP BY t.product,s.sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as follows:

```
SELECT p.sku "skuid", c.product "prod",
       LISTAGG(c.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY c.product) AS catids
  FROM category c
  INNER JOIN prod p 
    ON c.product = p.prod
  ORDER BY "skuid", c.product;
```

Also you can check this;
[it is more complicated version of usage together of listagg and join functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117553/sql-problem-with-multiple-linked-tables)